# Datatable pagination on newly added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, pagination

I am using `datatable` plugin for table pagination. It works fine with pre-loaded table ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/10gct428/)).

But the problem is when I am adding new rows through `jquery`. Since there is no page lad while adding the new rows, pagination doesn't seem to be applied for the table.

You can click on the '`add new row`' button to insert more rows.

Here is the **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/10gct428/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to add a row in a datatable

**Step 1:** Store your datatable in a variable

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

**Step 2:** Declare an array which later inserted in your datatable as new row

```
var tds = [];
```

**Step 3:** Push each td value in your `tds` as your row column

```
tds.push($(this).html());
```

**Finally:** insert your new data in the datatable

```
table.row.add(tds).draw( false );
```

So your final javascript code will be like this

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$("#insert-more").click(function () {
     $("#example").each(function () {
         var tds = [];
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds.push($(this).html());
         });
         table.row.add(tds).draw( false );
     });
});
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/10gct428/8/)